# Jquery Uploader not saving to a folder in the site root

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload

im trying to integrate the Jquery Uploader into my website >> http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

The problem I am having is that I cant seem to get it save the folder I want to to save to.

In the UploadHander.php I have the following settings >>

```
'script_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/',

        'upload_dir' => dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']).'./images/machinery/',

        'upload_url' => $this->get_full_url().'./images/machinery/',
```

This results in an image uploaded url that looks like this >>

http://domain.com/rcsetch/up/server/php/machinery/image.jpg

Other than putting my php files in the root of the website, im not sure how to get it to work, as what I want it to do is upload the files to http://domain.com/images/machinery
and not to the create a folder in the directory where all the php files for the uploader are located.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your following line:

```
'upload_dir' => dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']).'./images/machinery/',
```

for this one:

```
'upload_dir' => dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']).'/images/machinery/',
```

As `dirname()` returns directory names without ending `/` you were wrongly setting up the upload path dir.

Comment: This then puts it in http://domain.com/rcsetch/up/server/php./images/machinery/image.jpg

Comment: I don't think so, what is the output of your `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` variable ?

Answer (score 0):

Try `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` instead of `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']`.

```
'upload_dir' => $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/images/machinery/',
```

More info [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).